# trying to turn a python dictionary into some code

Tags: python, function, dictionary, key

I have a giant dictionary where the keys have varied amounts of values, but to test if this would work I used this as a sample

```
pretend_dict = {
'GLOW IN THE DARK': ['GLOW DARK', 'GL DARK', '429'], 'SPARKLE GOLD': ['SP GOLD', '500'], 'GOLD': '1235'
}
```

I'm trying to turn that dictionary into something that looks like this

```
elif color == regexer(color, 'GLOW IN THE DARK') or color == regexer(color, 'GLOW DARK'), or color == regexer(color, 'GL DARK') or color == regexer(color, '429'):
    color = 'GLOW IN THE DARK'
    temp_list.append(color)
    continue
elif color == regexer(color, 'SPARKLE GOLD') or color == regexer(color, 'SP GOLD'), or color == regexer(color, '500'):
    color = 'SPARKLE GOLD'
    temp_list.append(color)
    continue
elif color == regexer(color, 'GOLD') or color == regexer(color, '1235'):
    color = '1235'
    temp_list.append(color)
    continue
```

I really have no idea how to do this when each key might have 0 or 3 or 10 values, but I tried this code and I tried using *args but unsurprisingly nothing happened

```
def code_maker(*color_abbr):
    for color in pretend_dict:
        main_name = iter(color)
        values_view = color.values()
        value_iterator = iter(values_view)
        color_abbr = next(value_iterator)
        first_code_part = 'elif color == regexer(color, "'+main_name+'")'
        color_abbr = 'or color == regexer(color, "'+color_abbr+'")'
        colon = ':'
        last_code_part = '\n\tcolor = "'+main_name+'"\n\ttemp_list.append(color)\n\tcontinue'
        returner = first_code_part + color_abbr + colon + last_code_part
    return returner

print(code_maker)
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: Put all the `color == regexer(...)` into a list, then use `' or '.join(list_of_comparisons)`

Answer (score 0):

this should do want you want:

```
pretend_dict = {
    'GLOW IN THE DARK': ['GLOW DARK', 'GL DARK', '429'], 'SPARKLE GOLD': ['SP GOLD', '500'], 'GOLD': '1235'
}


def color_maker(colors) -> str:
    output = ""
    for key, value in colors.items():
        values = [key]
        if isinstance(value, list):
            values.extend(value)
        else:
            values.append(value)
        output += "elif "
        output += " or ".join([f"color == regexer(color, '{v}')" for v in values])
        output += f":\n  color = '{key}'\n"
        output += "  temp_list.append(color)\n"
        output += "  continue\n"

    return output


print(color_maker(pretend_dict))
```

result will be:

```
elif color == regexer(color, 'GLOW IN THE DARK') or color == regexer(color, 'GLOW DARK') or color == regexer(color, 'GL DARK') or color == regexer(color, '429'):
  color = 'GLOW IN THE DARK'
  temp_list.append(color)
  continue
elif color == regexer(color, 'SPARKLE GOLD') or color == regexer(color, 'SP GOLD') or color == regexer(color, '500'):
  color = 'SPARKLE GOLD'
  temp_list.append(color)
  continue
elif color == regexer(color, 'GOLD') or color == regexer(color, '1235'):
  color = 'GOLD'
  temp_list.append(color)
  continue
```

the result is not exactly what you have given as result. The last value is `GOLD` instead of `1235` because the others get the key of the dict, the last one gets the value instead, i do not know if this is intended.

In your result you have some `,` before `or`, my result does not, but i think this was not intended.